# How to parse a string which is in particular format into HashMap?

Tags: java, parsing, hashmap

I have a String which is coming in particular format so I want to parse that string into map. I have a below method which parses String to a Map and it works fine.

```
  public static Map<String, String> parseStringToMap(String payload) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    try {
      for (String part : payload.split("\\|")) {
        String[] subparts = part.split("=", 2);
        map.put(subparts[0], subparts[1]);
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return map;
  }
```

Sample example of a string:

```
"type=3|Id=23456|user=13456"
"type=3|Id=23456|user=13456|type=3"
```

It might be possible that same key can appear many times in the same string payload so I need to overwrite the value for that key in my mutable map.

Also if my string payload is not in this below format then I would like to return empty map back. My string format will always be like this and if it is not in this format then I would return empty map back. Right now I am not sure how can I add this logic so that I can return empty map if this case arises?

```
"a=b|c=d|e=f"
```

I am working with Java 7. What is the best and efficient way to do this?

My spec is this only. My String will always be in this format:

```
"a=b|c=d|e=f"
```

It will never starts with any special character.

Comment: Update your question with the specification.  Is this FIX?  If so, then there are probably already libraries you should be using to parse it.

Comment: I just updated it. Let me know if you have any question. It will always be in this format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a regex to ensure that the incoming payload string has the correct format:

```
public static Map<String, String> parseStringToMap(String payload) {
    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    if (!payload.matches("[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+(\\|[A-Za-z0-9]+=[A-Za-z0-9]+)*")) {
        // return empty map
        return map;
    }

    // your original code here
}
```

With regard to your concern about the same key appearing more than once, the default behavior of a hashmap would be to overwrite, so you might already be covered in this case.  Just write your key/value pairs as they arise and you will automatically be overwriting old values with the new ones.

Comment: Regex looks good. But when I test it with this string `":a=b|c=d|e=f"`, it doesnt return empty map and this format doesnt matches with my specification.

Comment: You never mentioned _anywhere_ that colon has special meaning.  I won't make unlimited changes to my answer to meet your requirements.

Comment: If you tell us the spec maybe there is a simple update to my answer.

Comment: My spec is that my String will always be in this format `"a=b|c=d|e=f"`. There won't be any special character infront of it.

Comment: @user1950349 So why are you complaining about `:a=b|c=d|e=f`?

Comment: @EJP Because it starts with a certain blacklisted character.

Comment: But he just said there won't be any special characters in front of it. He needs to clarify.

Comment: @user1950349 I edited my answer such that only letters and numbers can be the first character of your message.

Comment: @EJP What I meant was if in case someone start sending some character infront of it then I should fail and return empty map.

Comment: @user1950349 EJP's concern is that you still haven't told us _which_ characters can or cannot be in front.  I assumed letters and numbers, but perhaps that is wrong.

Comment: Does this apply everywhere in the message, or only at the start?

Comment: Thinking more on this, I think it applies everywhere in the message.